# Problem with Time Comparison in Rails AR Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time, comparison

I'm running Rails 3.0.4 with a PostgreSQL Database and i created a DateTime field called `ordered_at`.

I set it by creation with Time.now and i want to query the ordered_at field with something like `where("ordered_at > ?", params[:later_than]`, but if I put later than with something like 1.minute.from_now, I'm getting results where no results should be.

In Detail: `ordered_at` is `2011-03-08 11:11:49` and `params[:later_than]` is `2011-03-08 11:09:58 UTC`.

I think that is because of the time zone in the Time object, which doesn't exists in the database (The ordered_At field is a `timestamp without time zone` Datatype).

Does anyone had the same problem and can help me?

Comment: Could you check the logs and paste here the SQL query that gets generated out of this?

Comment: The SQL looks like that: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "course_orders" WHERE "course_orders"."finished" = 't' AND (DATE(ordered_at) = '2011-03-08') AND (ordered_at > '2011-03-08 12:16:09.708236' )`. One hint: I'm generating my data with fixtures for the tests

Comment: So this is one of my fixtures: `course_order_for_today_order_of_hans:
  ordered_at: <%= Time.now - 1.hour %>` And this will set the time to somewhat not in UTC

Comment: @leons...`<%= Time.now.utc - 1.hour %>` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.
The root of evil was in my fixtures.

You have to set times in your fixtures like that:

```
  ordered_at: <%= (30.minutes.ago).iso8601 %>
```

otherwise you will get the timezone of the database/server

Answer (score 0):

The thing you have to remember is Rails store the time in your database in UTC. Rails convert the time into UTC and sets it as the standard to look at in the database. So if you have `params[:later_than]` as `2011-03-08 11:11:49 UTC` or any time for that matter with any time zone, Rails will convert it into UTC time zone before inserting into the SQL query. If you are saving Time.now into the database, `Time.now` will be the server time or local machine time with the time zone in which the machine is set. Before saving to database, Rails will convert it to UTC and save it. So, at database level everything will be converted to UTC and then will be compared so avoiding confusion.